# Keep tomcat (JULI) logs indefinitely

Tags: tomcat

On our `tomcat7` server we keep logs for all emails sent by the server.
Log is configured in `/etc/tomcat7/logging.properties` as follows:

```
4mail.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = ALL
4mail.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
4mail.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = mail.
```

I want these logs to be compressed daily and kept indefinitely.  At the moment they are compressed daily and cleared monthly.  How do I configure this?